# QtCreator / Debugger, Locals and Expressions

Tags: c++, debugging, qt-creator

I've been using QtCreator for over a year, today I've observed some behaviour which is new.  I'm not sure if its functionality that has always been there and triggered by an accidental key stroke.

I am using QtCreator

```
    Qt Creator 4.2.1
    Based on Qt 5.8.0 (GCC 5.3.1 20160406 (Red Hat 5.3.1-6), 64 bit)
    Built on Jan 20 2017 01:20:15
    From revision 7071b61e02
```

At some point the debugger watch window has stopped working properly, I know that previously I have been able to expand pointers and drill down into the class to reveal the state of members. In a lot of cases now I get the pointer displayed and then  where the address would normally be displayed, if I attempt to expand the pointer it shows just [0] and nothing else.

Parameters do not always appear in the "Locals and Expressions" window either. I've also noticed that 'this' no longer appears when debugging an object.

This is making development very difficult.

The question is, is this an option hiding somewhere or is it a bug?

[image]

The screen shot shows the debugger with a breakpoint in the displayed member function, notice in the Locals and Expressions view there is no 'this' and there is also missing local parameters for pobjLayout and pobjGraphic.

Also notice that there are local variables (pointers) which are also missing from the view.

Not sure it will help, but here is a screenshot of the stack with a breakpoint.

[image]

Comment: Why vote to close this question without at least posting why?

Comment: The close vote was mine. It seems unclear what you're asking. Please edit to provide a clear question.

Comment: @owacoder, for clarity I've edited and posted a question, although I think it was pretty obvious.

Comment: Thanks. BTW, it's not just me. Stack Overflow seems to want pristine questions. I'll retract my vote. :-)

Comment: @owacoder, thank you.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot or example of your problem, please?

Comment: @owacoder, done.

Comment: Could you please also provide a screenshot of the stacktraces of the halting-thread, to understand "where" we are?

Comment: @MABVT, I think you are onto something there....my first thought was it doesn't matter it does it everywhere, but on stopping executing immediately on the first line, everything is ok, I will try to track it down

Comment: @MABVT, ok, I know now why 'this' doesn't appear, its because I was in a static method, but the other problems like local variables and pointers not showing content still exists.

Comment: I can just repeat :D Can you please provide the stacktrace, OR the exact location in the function...

Comment: @MABVT, I can't the application is huge and a stacktrace really isn't going to give you anything other that what calls what, there are no stack issues.

Comment: @MABVT, screenshot of stacktrace added.

Comment: does the "locals" view reflect the autolayout() or the pbojCreateGraphic() stackframe?

Comment: @MABVT, both autoLayout and pobjCreateLayout are static methods, all the others are not static methods.  The stack frame does not display correctly for either of the static methods, parameters are not all displayed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139994/discussion-between-mabvt-and-splatten).

Comment: Still no clues.

Comment: Can anyone suggest why this has happend?

Comment: A week on and still no solution...it seems the debugger is broken by something it is debugging, how can that happen?

Comment: According to QT its a bug in the current release and an update is due soon.